# Аргументы событий

Tags: c#, winforms

Прощу прощения если ломаю какие то паттерны и т.д., я о них пока ничего не знаю.

```
    public class MyClass
    {
       public bool SozdanieIOtobragenieFormi()
       {
          ...

            form.Controls.Add(textBox);
            form.Controls.Add(button);

            button.Click += Button_Click;

            form.ShowDialog();

            return true;
       }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Логика
        }
    }
```

Как в событии передать ссылку на `textBox` и ссылку на `form` ?

Цель: Получить при событии значение из `textBox` и закрыть `form`

Мне нужно построить подходящий класс с наследованием от `EventArgs` и передавать его как параметр ?

Comment: Ну попробуйте лямбду с захватом переменой, что то типа `button.click += (s, e) => { messagebox.show(mytextbox.text);};

Comment: TextBox и другие необходимые компоненты можно сделать _полями_: `private TextBox textBox;`. После чего можно использовать их в обраобтчике события.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, в итоге так и сделал, имею доп. поле под эту форму, но думал как то просто передать, чтобы не иметь лишнего поля.

Comment: вам мой комментарий не помог? Он имеено то делает, что вы спросили

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо! Постараюсь разобраться. Дело в том, что не понимаю пока как она работает.

Comment: При захвате переменных компилятором будет автоматически создан анонимный класс, в которых они станут полями. То есть компилятор сделает работу за нас.

Comment: Кстати, вы в курсе, что sender в обработчике события кнопки - это сама кнопка? `Button btn = (Button)sender;` Это особенно полезно знать например, если вы хотите один обработчик для нескольких кнопок использовать. Да и в любом обработчике винформ sender - это контрол, в котором произошло событие, его только нужно привести к конкретному типу.